# cookie not saved to the browser

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, fetch

soo i have the following fetch api

```
    const loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const URL = "http://localhost:8000/auth/login/"
        let response = await fetch(URL, {
            // credentials: "include",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: e.target.username.value,
                password: e.target.password.value,
            }),
        })
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log(response)
        } else {
            setLoginStatus("Invalid credentials")
            loginStatusRef.current.style.visibility = "visible"
        }
    }
```

This is the response of the above fetch

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:3000
Allow POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length 37
Content-Type application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy same-origin
Date Thu, 25 Aug 2022 16:44:07 GMT
Referrer-Policy same-origin
Server WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.5
Set-Cookie
    csrftoken=Ou23mE46QwuuJi37bVgsZq19NbEAzaFh; expires=Thu, 24 Aug 2023 16:44:07 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie
    sessionid=hyvv9uwwdi0m0blhb3ks6vzgtnyimxa6; expires=Thu, 08 Sep 2022 16:44:07 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-Frame-Options DENY
```

when i try to enable `credentials:'include'`,i get the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/auth/login/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

i have already enabled `cors` in django

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000', ]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    . . . 
    "corsheaders"
]
```

as you can see, a cookie `sessionid` is being returned but its not saved on browser. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

- Currently you have **default** behaviour that CORS-preflight requests must never include credentials.
- Specify **`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true`** in response to indicate that the actual request can be made with credentials that should solve it.

> The **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** header indicates whether or not the response to the request can be exposed when the credentials flag is *true*. When used as part of a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the actual request can be made using credentials.so if a request is made for a resource with credentials, if this header is not returned with the resource, the response is ignored by the browser and not returned to web content.
> Note that simple **GET** requests are not preflighted.